# Weird Button Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, uilabel

It's my first try on IOS animation, so if I'm worry from the very beginning, just tell me the right direction.

All I want: when I click `ButtonOne`, `Label` disappears slowly.
The code as below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var isHidden: Bool = false

    @IBAction func clickButtonOne(sender: UIButton) {
        isHidden = !isHidden
        if isHidden {
            labelHeight.constant = 0
        } else {
            labelHeight.constant = 60
        }
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                () -> Void in
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Before I click `ButtonOne`:
[image: ButtonOne+Label+ButtonTwo]
After I click `ButtonOne`(label shrinks from bottom to top):
[image: ButtonOne+halfTopLabel+ButtonTwo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UILabel is disappearing, but it's content is still visible.

You need to set the `clipsToBounds` property of the UILabel to `true`.

```
label.clipsToBounds = true
```

You can set the same property in the interface builder by checking the `Clip Subviews` property in the attributes inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also animate `UIView.alpha` property:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var isHidden: Bool = false

    @IBAction func clickButtonOne(sender: UIButton) {
        isHidden = !isHidden
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1
        if isHidden {
            alpha = 0
            labelHeight.constant = 0
        } else {
            labelHeight.constant = 60
        }
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                () -> Void in
                self.button.alpha = alpha
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried label.text="" myself, it works like alpha=0, but I think ZeMoon's solution is better. BTW, thank your for the editing, it's really embarrassing...